# Autosave form on idleness

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code that is supposed to autosubmit(save) a form with the name "project" when the user is idle.  This is code I found on a tutorial website(forget the name), I tried it and it only refreshes the page?

```
<!-- Set auto save timeout in milliseconds 
<script type="text/javascript">
attachEvent(window,'load',function(){
  var idleSeconds = 5;
  var idleTimer;
  function resetTimer(){
    clearTimeout(idleTimer);
    idleTimer = setTimeout(whenUserIdle,idleSeconds*1000);
  }
  attachEvent(document.body,'mousemove',resetTimer);
  attachEvent(document.body,'keydown',resetTimer);
  attachEvent(document.body,'click',resetTimer);

  resetTimer(); // Start the timer when the page loads
});

function whenUserIdle(){
        document.project.submit();
        window.location = location.href;
}

function attachEvent(obj,evt,fnc,useCapture){
  if (obj.addEventListener){
    obj.addEventListener(evt,fnc,!!useCapture);
    return true;
  } else if (obj.attachEvent){
    return obj.attachEvent("on"+evt,fnc);
  }
} 
</script> -->
```

Form Code :

```
<form name="project" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="invoice-form" method="post"  class="invoice-form" role="form" novalidate>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that is refreshing the page `window.location = location.href;` Try removing it.

And you also need to make sure your form's attribute `name` is replacing "project" in `document.project.submit();`.

For example

```
<form name="test_form"></form>

document.test_form.submit();
```

Edit:
Alright, the the function should just be

```
function whenUserIdle() {
    document.project.submit();
}
```

Comment: I know that it refreshes, its supposed to, it just isnt submitting the form like it should

Comment: It is because you're reloading the page before the submit, you need to send the data before reloading the page

Comment: @Steven Consider submitting the form via AJAX, then redirect once it is successfully submitted.

Comment: I agree with Derek, ajax is the best way to go, then you can get a callback from your php when the form has been submitted. But if you don't want to involve it, just remove the page refresh.

Comment: @JonathanNielsen The page refresh is supposed to act in such a way as to keep the user on the current page AFTER the form is submitted.  I removed it, and verified it autosaves correctly then, but after submit, it goes to a seperate page.  I want it to autosave, then refresh back to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing an actual form submission, consider doing an AJAX request:

```
function whenUserIdle(){
  var formData = {}; // assemble the form data here
  $.post( "/form-submission-route", formData, function( responseData) {
    // do something with result, if you like
    // perhaps clear the form or throw up a notification
  });
}
```

Comment: I am totally unfamiliar with ajax.  The above code does make a certain amount of common sense, except how would the "assemble form data here" section work with sample data?